# Como limpar um evento

Tags: php, jquery

estou criando um sistema de comentário com resposta só que na hora de responder vai duas vezes para o banco quando envio um comentário, fiz o sistema de resposta em slide onde você abre um e fecha o outro, só que quando abre o próximo para comentar e fecha o anterior ainda é carregado e conta como se fosse duas respostas alguém sabe como resolver ?

código

```
    function addEventosRespostas() {
        $(document).on("click", ".resposta", function(){
            var id = $(this).children('input').val();

            $('.coment').find('.resp').fadeOut("slow");
            $(this).parents('.coment').find('.resp').fadeIn("slow");

            $(document).on("submit","form", function() {

                var texto = $(this).children('textarea').val();
                var coment_id = $(this).find('#id_coment').val();
                var id_user_coment = $(this).find('#id_user_coment').val();

                    $.post('swith/viwer.php',{
                        acao: 'resposta', texto: texto, coment_id: coment_id, id_user_coment: id_user_coment},
                            function(){
                                $('.dialog').fadeIn();
                                $('form textarea').val("");
                                $('form input[type = submit]').val("responder");
                                $('.closemodal').click(function(){
                                        $('.dialog').fadeOut();
                                });
                            });
            return false;
            });

        });
    }

// Exibir mais comentários



    $('#load').on("click",function(){

        loadmo = $(this);
        var video = $('#link').val();
        var numcom = $('.comentar .com').length;

        $.post('swith/viwer.php',{
            acao:'comentarios', video: video, numcom: numcom},function(contcom){

            if(contcom => 1){
                $.post('swith/viwer.php',{
                    acao:'morecoment', video: video, numcom: numcom},function(morecom){

                    $('.comentar .com:last').after(morecom);
                    $('.comentar .com').fadeIn("slow");
                    addEventosRespostas();





                }); 

            }

            if(contcom > 1){

            }else{
               loadmo.fadeOut("fast"); 
            }
        });
    });

// Responder Comentário        



        addEventosRespostas();
```

Código php

```
<div class='comentar  fl-left'>
                        <div class='coment com' >

                                <?php 

                    if($foto == "" || $foto == "uploads/"):
                        echo  "<a href='user?id={$id}'><img class='fl-left' src='".REQUIRE_PATH."/css/boot/icons/thumb.png'></a>";
                    else:
                        echo  "<a href='user?id={$id}'><img class='fl-left' src='{$imx['foto']}'></a>";
                    endif;
                    ?>
                   <p><small class='fontze1'>Comentado por:</small> <?=$nome?> <small>Em:  </small> <?=$date?> <small>As: </small> <?=$hora?></p>

                   <div class="comentando">
                       <p><?=nl2br($comentario)?></p></div>
                       <div class='fl-right resposta'>Responder<input type='hidden' value='<?=$big[id] ?>' name='idcoment'>
                       </div>
                       <div class=' resp' style='display:none'>
                           <form method='post' id="comentarios" class="formulario" >
                               <input type="hidden" value="<?= $big['id'] ?>" id="id_coment" >
                               <input type="hidden" value="<?= $_SESSION['mail'] ?>" id="id_user_coment" >
                               <textarea id="texto"></textarea>  

                               <input class='btn btn-green' type='submit' value='responder' name='responder'>
                           </form>
                       </div>
                   </div>
```

Comment: Podes colocar o HTML que tens para podermos responder melhor?

Answer (score 0):

Isso está acontecendo porque você adiciona o evento:

```
 $(document).on("submit","form",function());
```

duas vezes, então se um formulário der submit ele vai cair em ambos entende?
Fiz um exemplo onde você claramente vai ver isso acontecendo.

[Exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/358qjtxb/)

Uma solução seria apenas adicionar o código uma unica vez exemplo :

```
 $(document).on("submit","form",function());
```

Assim vai pegar todos os submits de "form".
Espero ter ajudado, caso tenha restado duvida ou precise que eu te explique melhor pode comentar abaixo.

Comment: então no caso eu não tenho dois eventos submit o outro evento é click

Comment: Você chama a função addEventosRespostas() quantas vezes ? tem como postar mais codigo ?

Comment: acabei de postar agora para melhor exemplificação